# onkeyup event is not working when the textbox has "data-role=tagsinput" specified

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the code I have been working on,

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var request;

        function sendInfo(){
            var v=document.main.io.value;
            var url="myjsp.jsp?val="+v;

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                request=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if(window.ActiveXObject){
            request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            try{
                request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;
                request.open("GET",url,true);
                request.send();
            }catch(e){
                alert("Unable to connect to server");
            }
        }

        function getInfo(){
            if(request.readyState==4){
                var m=request.responseText;
                document.getElementById('sam').innerHTML=m;

            }
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="main">
        <input type="text" name="io" onkeyup="sendInfo()" data-role="tagsinput"/>
    </form>
    <div id="sam">
    </div>
</body>
```

I have not included the "myjsp.jsp" file as I'm sure that nothing is wrong with it.

If I create the textbox as follows,

```
<input type="text" name="io" onkeyup="sendInfo()"/>
```

then the function "sendInfo()" is called but if I add "data-role='tagsinput'" as,

```
  <input type="text" name="io" onkeyup="sendInfo()" data-role="tagsinput"/>
```

then the function "sendInfo()" is not called.

I have to write `data-role="tagsinput"` for generating the bootstrap tags, but I also want the function "**sendInfo()**" to execute.
Any suggestions on this situation??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the event listener with javascript:

```
window.attachEvent = function(){
    document.querySelector("input[data-role='tagsinput']").onkeyup(function(){
        sendInfo();
    });
};
window.addEventListener("load", attachEvent);
```

to make sure for accessibility of your function, define it in window context:

```
window.sendInfo=function sendInfo(){/.../}
```

and you can also try body onload attribute:

```
<body onload="attachEvent();">...</body>
```

Comment: I removed "onkeyup=sendInfo()" from the textbox and added your code but still no suceess.